# How can a non-EU citizen become a Danish citizen?

Tags: visa, citizenship, uk-citizens, denmark

... And how difficult is it/how does it work? I am confused about how you could get a job for a work visa? What happens if your income comes from an independant/freelance career (e.g. like a photographer or artist)... Could it still be possible to get a residency permit (and eventually become a citizen)...? I intended to move once I was financially stable/had some savings.

If anyone could explain how it works, any information, I would appreciate it.

I am a British citizen but in case UK citizens become non-EU citizens after the Brexit vote, I want to prepare for the worst (which would be becoming a non-EU citizen) and make sure I am able to move country.

I have basic Danish language skills and trying to learn Danish still. I have lived in Denmark for 3 months before. I was also considering Faroe Islands as a place to move to.

Thanks for any kind & helpful replies

Comment: [Danish nationals living on the Faroes aren't EU Citzens and it isn't part of the EU](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faroe_Islands_and_the_European_Union). This may affect your plans.

Answer (score 4):

I think the very **first** thing you should do is find a job and move to Denmark. Then when the formal announcement is made, the position of UK citizens living in the EU, and EU citizens living in the UK, will be a chief negotiating point for both parties. Most likely both sides will want each citizen to retain the right of abode that they already exercise on the effective date of the declaration.

Upon arrival set yourself up with an EU residence permit. See: http://www.statsforvaltning.dk/site.aspx?p=6028

The second thing you should do is, once settled in Denmark, research how to get on an immigration path to citizenship there.

Keep in mind that there is a strong Eurosceptic political feeling in Denmark; it would not be outlandish to see them exit the EU in the future. So, nothing is certain so think about your goals, and how happy you would be with various future outcomes.

Final note: based on your name I'm assuming you are male.  If I am wrong and you are female, I would strongly advise you to go to Faroe instead. Because of the shortage on women in Faroe, there is a strong chance for you to find a marriage there.

Answer (score -2):

I lived in Denmark and was married to a Danish citizen. We both live in the US now. Denmark is making it very difficult for non-EU residents to live in Denmark, let alone becoming Danish citizens. However, you have two things in your favor. First, British citizens remain popular in Denmark, and the UK is still in the EU and will be for another two years. (Gee, why doesn't GB re-vote?) Anyway, speed is of the essence. Learn as much Danish as possible. It is a requirement for citizenship, and it is granted far less than residency. But for your purposes, residency is a viable option. I read the other post about the Faroes, but that is complicated. Plus, you'd have better luck finding a job on Neptune. Finally, if you have friends in DK, visit and explore your additional options. Good luck!

Comment: This does gives some suggestions but doesn't really answer the question. You should elaborate on some of the points